# Selecting a time Interval(collection View)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bd9F.png)
In my project i have to select the time interval(range) as the below image.

Here is the code i am using, i have added a collectionView :

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var time = ["0.00","1.00","2.00","3.00","4.00","5.00","6.00","7.00","8.00","9.00","10.00","11.00","12.00","1.00","2.00","3.00","4.00","5.00","6.00","7.00","8.00","9.00","10.00","11.00"]
var timeVal = ["AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","AM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM","PM"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return time.count

}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! timeCell

    cell.timeLabel.text = time[indexPath.row]
    cell.intervalLabel.text = timeVal[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width/7) , (collectionView.frame.size.height))
    }
}
```

And i appears as the below image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqvgE.png)

But i am confused how to implement that interval selection(Two time intervals).Please suggest.

Comment: I don't understand the question right. What do you want to do?

Comment: Please check the added images. I want to select a particular time interval such as from 8 AM to 10 AM.

Comment: yes but how? by dragging? by selecting two collectionViewCells as start and end? there are several ways to achieve this

Comment: By dragging start and ends of the above view

Comment: Then you need to implement a panGestrueRecognizer . Here is a example: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-gestures-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: if not by dragging, but by clicking then you could allow for `MultipleSelection` on your `CollectionView`. Then implement some logic in the `didSelectRow(at: indexPath)` such that you make your cell's backgrounds change based on the row that you clicked. You'd need some more logic to make sure that you can't select more than two rows (one start, one end). :)